# Removing letter from cell

Tags: excel-2010

I have lists of dates that look like this 07-Aug-17 A. Some dates have the A at the end, some do not. I want to remove the A at the end of the cell. Everything I try either removes the A at the end as well as the A in Apr, or Aug. Or it removes the A at the end, and if there isn't an A at the end, then it removes part of the date itself.

Comment: please provide code for what you have tried

Comment: Check if the cell value is a date first - `isdate("07-Aug-17")` returns _TRUE_, `isdate("07-Aug-17 A")` returns _FALSE_.

Answer (score 0):

if you have dates in fixed format like 14-Apr-17
14-Aug-17 A
14-Aug-17
14-Sep-17
 you can use left function as the length of each date will be of 9 characters in this case.

use : =VALUE(LEFT(A1,9)). Do not forget to change the format of result cell to dates.

Comment: Have to disagree there - the text `14-Apr-17` is 9 characters long, the text displayed in the formula bar `07/08/2018` is 10 characters long, the actual value that Excel uses - `42839` is 5 characters long.

Comment: you are right. However in case of date if you give 9 charecters it will take full date, where as in case of 14-apr-17 A it is text and left will give first 9 characters, which is needed. So this formula will work. Please try this once.